# Return multiple result with getter in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, getter

I wrote a function where I have to return one of the same question with three different answers.

I managed to pull one question (as I should because it's the same fr all three), but I have trouble figuring out how to pull all the answers.

Dumping *$questions* return all three but my foreach returns just first one.

```
$questions = $this->getQuestionRepository()->findBy([
        'user'      => $user,
    ]);

    $result = [];
    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $result['question'] = $question->getQuestion();
        foreach ($questions as $answer) {
            $result['answers'] = [$answer->getAnswer()];
        }
    }

    return $result;
```

Result:

```
"data": {
    "question": "What is your name?",
    "answers": [
        "First answer"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$questions = $this->getQuestionRepository()->findBy([
        'user'      => $user,
    ]);

    $result = [];
    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $result['question'] = $question->getQuestion();
        foreach ($questions as $answer) {
            $result['answers'][] = $answer->getAnswer();
        }
    }

    return $result;
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!  @Kaleem I just have one question, why it show 9 results as in database I have 3? Do I have error in code?